# Unable to load MNIST hand written text dataset from fetch_openml()

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, mnist, image-classification

I came to know that **fetch_mldata()** doesn't work anymore. **fetch_mldata(**) is dead because it relied on a website that died. I replaced it with **fetch_openml()**, which relies on *https://openml.org*

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, cache=True)
mnist.target = mnist.target.astype(np.int8) # fetch_openml() returns targets as strings
print(mnist)
```

But i am facing the below error:

```
OpenMLError: Dataset mnist_784 with version 1 not found.
```

does anyone have a solution? thanks in advance.